# Ansible lookup a single line in a json file

Tags: json, ansible

I need to read an ip line from  a dynamic generated json file and add it to a configuration file on the server.

At Ansible home page i found two modules which would help:

- lookup module

- fileinline module

The lookup examples however show  looking up for the whole contents of a file using this phrase `"{{ lookup('file', '/etc/foo.txt') }}"`
How could i filter the result into reading a single line?

Does anybody know a good way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably do want a special key from a JSON dict I guess? If it's just a random line which can not be accessed inside the JSON struct it will be hard. You would need to grep out the line in a separate task.

But let's assume you want a special value from a dict, then you can convert the JSON to an object with the `from_json` filter:

```
{{ lookup('file', '/etc/foo.txt') | from_json }}
```

Now if you want the value of `bar` from the contained data structure, something like this should work:

```
{{ (lookup('file', '/etc/foo.txt') | from_json).get('bar') }}
```

Comment: Unfortunately .get('bar') filter seems not to work with Ansible. I got " no filter named 'from_json.get"

Comment: The parentheses are important. `from_json.get(...)` will not work.

Comment: i did include the paretheses.                                                                         "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/foo.txt')| from_json.get('title')}}"

Comment: Nope, you did not :) Try this: `"{{ (lookup('file', '/etc/foo.txt') | from_json).get('title')}}"`

Comment: If anyone wants a way to pull from a url, I figured this out from the docs. `(lookup('url', 'https://path/to/remote/json', split_lines=False) | from_json).get('findthis'))` You can chain multiple `.get()` calls as well. Just make sure you don't forget your parens.